# Storyboard gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

After creating an Xcode project from the iPad "master/detail" storyboard template, I cannot seem to find the UIGestureRecognizer instance that's responsible for the Mail-style swipe to show the master view in portrait mode.

I need to do this in order to make it ignore touches on certain UI elements, but it doesn't seem to be handled by any of the 4 gesture recognizers returned by the `gestureRecognizers` method of the master view. When I set a delegate on them, its functions only get called when interacting with the master view itself, and not with a swipe on, e.g. the detail area. The detail view returns an empty array from `gestureRecognizers`.

A project-wide search for "gesture" reveals nothing, and I see no gesture recognizers in the storyboard. Where is this handler created and managed in the default Xcode "master/detail" template, and how can I access it in order to set a delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect it is on the split view controller itself rather than the master or detail view controllers. You can turn it on or off using the `presentsWithGesture` property (5.1 and later only).

Comment: Hmm - well, turning off `presentsWithGesture` on the split view does indeed disable the swipe, but `[[self view] gestureRecognizers]` still returns an empty array. Or at least it does in `viewDidLoad`; perhaps the recognizer gets set up later?

Comment: I realize that comment was unclear: I tested turning off `presentsWithGesture`, but `[[self view] gestureRecognizers]` returns an empty array even when I leave it on.

Comment: Ah, yes - they get set up later. In `viewDidAppear`, the gesture recognizer is returned. Thanks!